# Classnot found. Null Pointer exception when i wanna change .Jar to .exe

Tags: java

I have created a java application to connect to a MySQL database. Once through the program install creator, I created a .exe .

This executable runs, and the first form is login. When he tries to access the database to confirm the details of login gives this error.

java.lang.NullPointerException
Someone can help me solve this? The path is correct because if run the .jar the application runs normally.

I apologize for the inconvenience.

enter image description here

Only have this to try to explain better my question :S

I'm so sorry... I'm running an executable version from my java application.

Answer (score 0):

We will need more information than this, some things that you can provide that would be helpful are...

- Your packaging tool (what you use to get from jar to exe)
- Code
- A stack trace